# Creating a method at runtime and System.IO Exception

Tags: c#, reflection

Hello I have been trying to figure this out for a while now and cannot get it correct. I have found a few threads that do similar to what I want to do. but I keep getting a system.Io Assembly cannot be found compile and run the string that was created.

```
    private bool CalculateBooleanExpression(string expression)
    {
        var classExpression = stringClass.Replace(ReplaceMe,expression);

        var complierParameters = new CompilerParameters()
        {
            GenerateExecutable=false,
            GenerateInMemory = true
        };
        var complier = new CSharpCodeProvider();

        var compilerResults = complier.CompileAssemblyFromSource(complierParameters, classExpression);

//break point here compilerResults.CompiledAssembly is null
        object typeInstance = compilerResults.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("BooleanEvaluator");

        MethodInfo methodInfo = typeInstance.GetType().GetMethod("Calculate");

        bool value = (bool)methodInfo.Invoke(typeInstance, new object[] { });

        return true;
    }
```

> Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\james.tays\AppData\Local\Temp\22ozhhme.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

can anyone tell me how to debug this so i can figure out where there error is?

EDIT:
While debugging I have found this error too.

> error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods}

Comment: `CompileAssemblyFromSource` returns a `CompilerResults` object that contains a load of information about the result of attempting to compile the assembly, including errors and the actual output path. Could you do some more debugging on your own to see if there were any errors during compilation?

Comment: I have updated top

Comment: Most likely the value of the const or variable `stringClass` is incorrect

Comment: Can you include the value of `expression` that causes the error? Given the error, you have uncompilable code.

Comment: Try using `CompileAssemblyFromFile` if you want to compile from an existing saved source file instead using `CompileAssemblyFromSource` which used when the string contains compilable source code instead of a file path. Which line throwing the error, and has the compiler generating output DLL file?